# ReadyBoost - Dedicated 128Gb microSD with adapter - Cache configuration loops forever

Tags: cache, readyboost

**ReadyBoost cache configuration keeps going forever**

*What I am trying to do:*
Dedicate to ReadyBoost a 128Gb microSD loaded in its SD adapter.

- MicroSD is TOP speed and unformatted
- I only defined a label before applying ReadyBoos

*System:*

- Lenovo X270
- Windows 10 64bit
- 16Gb Ram (1 SODIMM)
- 512 Gb HDD

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Giulio Lol 16gb  yeah ReadyBoost is pointless on your machine.  Try formatting the SD card though.

Comment: @Keltari, tried with NTFS and no luck. It just hangs, both that I choose to fully dedicate the card to RB or to partially reserve a share to RB. Explorer just freezes while the cache is being configured, and it stays so. I also disabled Acronis TI Active protection but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.

According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost#Requirements):

> Windows 7 allows up to eight devices for a maximum of 256 GB of additional memory, with up to 32 GB on a single storage device.

I am not sure if this 32 GB limit is per partition, or per disk.  However, this is easy to test and determine for yourself.  I dont know why this particular limit exists.  Nor do I know if the limit is artificial, or has a technical reason.  I couldnt find anything specific to Windows 10.  However, there is also no reason to assume it would be different for Windows 10.

As I mentioned in the comments, with the specs you provided for your machine, ReadyBoost will have no benefit.  ReadyBoost was designed for low memory (below 4 GB) machines using Windows Vista, or newer.  Even older machines with 4 GB of RAM show very limited to no improvement.  With the speed of modern hard drives and the rise in memory, the ReadyBoost cache will almost never get read from.

Comment: Thank you @Keltari. I have indeed tried to apply the limited usage of 32Gb, and I see that on Explorer the ReadyBoost.sfcache is correctly created in the SD as soon as I activate it, but then it hangs. It worked fine on a previous 64Gb SD I used, but for some reason now the process seems to become unresponsive. I also tried to cancel the %Systemroot%\Prefetch content and restart the sysmain service.while I'd like to get to the end of this, I'll probably give up and just use the SD for extra storage or back-up.